# table extrude from solution envrionment's frame in exam document

Tags: tables, exam

I'm using the `exam` class, and I have tables in it's solution environment, but I found that a table extrudes from the frame of the solution environment at the bottom of the page, see the image shot below.

[image: image shot]

Also, here is the minimal code to demonstrate this issue, any one can help me to solve this issue? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\printanswers
\begin{questions}
\question this is the question
\begin{solution}
The DH parameters:

 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
 Link& $b_i$& $\theta_i$& $a_i$ & $\alpha_i$\\
  \hline
 1 & $b_1$ & $\theta_1$ & $a_1$& 0\\
  \hline
 2 & $b_2$ & $\theta_2$ & $a_2$& 0\\
  \hline
 3 & $b_3$ &0 & 0& 0\\
  \hline
 4& $b_4$ & $\theta_4$ & 0& 0\\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}

 \[T=T_1T_2T_3=
   \begin{bmatrix} C_1&-S_1&S_1&0\\S_1&C_1&-C_1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \begin{bmatrix}
   C_2&-S_2&0&a_2C_2\\S_2&C_2&0&a_2S_2\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \begin{bmatrix}  C_3&-S_3&0&a_3C_3\\S_3&C_3&0&a_3S_3\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \]

\end{solution}

\question this is the question
\begin{solution}
The DH parameters:

 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
 Link& $b_i$& $\theta_i$& $a_i$ & $\alpha_i$\\
  \hline
 1 & $b_1$ & $\theta_1$ & $a_1$& 0\\
  \hline
 2 & $b_2$ & $\theta_2$ & $a_2$& 0\\
  \hline
 3 & $b_3$ &0 & 0& 0\\
  \hline
 4& $b_4$ & $\theta_4$ & 0& 0\\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}

 \[T=T_1T_2T_3=
   \begin{bmatrix} C_1&-S_1&S_1&0\\S_1&C_1&-C_1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \begin{bmatrix}
   C_2&-S_2&0&a_2C_2\\S_2&C_2&0&a_2S_2\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \begin{bmatrix}  C_3&-S_3&0&a_3C_3\\S_3&C_3&0&a_3S_3\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \]

 \[T=T_1T_2T_3=
   \begin{bmatrix} C_1&-S_1&S_1&0\\S_1&C_1&-C_1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \begin{bmatrix}
   C_2&-S_2&0&a_2C_2\\S_2&C_2&0&a_2S_2\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \begin{bmatrix}  C_3&-S_3&0&a_3C_3\\S_3&C_3&0&a_3S_3\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \]

   \[T=T_1T_2T_3=
     \begin{bmatrix} C_1&-S_1&S_1&0\\S_1&C_1&-C_1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
     \begin{bmatrix}
     C_2&-S_2&0&a_2C_2\\S_2&C_2&0&a_2S_2\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
     \begin{bmatrix}  C_3&-S_3&0&a_3C_3\\S_3&C_3&0&a_3S_3\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
     \]

\end{solution}

\question this is the question
\begin{solution}
The DH parameters:

 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
 Link& $b_i$& $\theta_i$& $a_i$ & $\alpha_i$\\
  \hline
 1 & $b_1$ & $\theta_1$ & $a_1$& 0\\
  \hline
 2 & $b_2$ & $\theta_2$ & $a_2$& 0\\
  \hline
 3 & $b_3$ &0 & 0& 0\\
  \hline
 4& $b_4$ & $\theta_4$ & 0& 0\\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}

 \[T=T_1T_2T_3=
   \begin{bmatrix} C_1&-S_1&S_1&0\\S_1&C_1&-C_1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \begin{bmatrix}
   C_2&-S_2&0&a_2C_2\\S_2&C_2&0&a_2S_2\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \begin{bmatrix}  C_3&-S_3&0&a_3C_3\\S_3&C_3&0&a_3S_3\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \]

   \[T=T_1T_2T_3=
     \begin{bmatrix} C_1&-S_1&S_1&0\\S_1&C_1&-C_1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
     \begin{bmatrix}
     C_2&-S_2&0&a_2C_2\\S_2&C_2&0&a_2S_2\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
     \begin{bmatrix}  C_3&-S_3&0&a_3C_3\\S_3&C_3&0&a_3S_3\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
     \]

\end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the tabular is vertically centred so half its size is in the depth which is why it causes problems. (The `exam` class could catch this but apparently not) so the easiest thing to do is use `[b]` so that the tabular has height rather than depth, then the table moves to the next page.

I added a `\nopagebreak` so the previous line stayed with the table and also moved over. In practice, you should probably add `\clearpage` before the question and move the whole question over.

Not directly related (and I didn't change here) you should not have a blank line before `\[` nor consecutive `\[\]` environments, it would be better to use a multi-line display from `amsmath`

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\printanswers
\begin{questions}
\question this is the question
\begin{solution}
The DH parameters:

 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
 Link& $b_i$& $\theta_i$& $a_i$ & $\alpha_i$\\
  \hline
 1 & $b_1$ & $\theta_1$ & $a_1$& 0\\
  \hline
 2 & $b_2$ & $\theta_2$ & $a_2$& 0\\
  \hline
 3 & $b_3$ &0 & 0& 0\\
  \hline
 4& $b_4$ & $\theta_4$ & 0& 0\\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}

 \[T=T_1T_2T_3=
   \begin{bmatrix} C_1&-S_1&S_1&0\\S_1&C_1&-C_1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \begin{bmatrix}
   C_2&-S_2&0&a_2C_2\\S_2&C_2&0&a_2S_2\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \begin{bmatrix}  C_3&-S_3&0&a_3C_3\\S_3&C_3&0&a_3S_3\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \]

\end{solution}

\question this is the question
\begin{solution}
The DH parameters:

 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
 Link& $b_i$& $\theta_i$& $a_i$ & $\alpha_i$\\
  \hline
 1 & $b_1$ & $\theta_1$ & $a_1$& 0\\
  \hline
 2 & $b_2$ & $\theta_2$ & $a_2$& 0\\
  \hline
 3 & $b_3$ &0 & 0& 0\\
  \hline
 4& $b_4$ & $\theta_4$ & 0& 0\\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}

 \[T=T_1T_2T_3=
   \begin{bmatrix} C_1&-S_1&S_1&0\\S_1&C_1&-C_1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \begin{bmatrix}
   C_2&-S_2&0&a_2C_2\\S_2&C_2&0&a_2S_2\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \begin{bmatrix}  C_3&-S_3&0&a_3C_3\\S_3&C_3&0&a_3S_3\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \]

 \[T=T_1T_2T_3=
   \begin{bmatrix} C_1&-S_1&S_1&0\\S_1&C_1&-C_1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \begin{bmatrix}
   C_2&-S_2&0&a_2C_2\\S_2&C_2&0&a_2S_2\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \begin{bmatrix}  C_3&-S_3&0&a_3C_3\\S_3&C_3&0&a_3S_3\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \]

   \[T=T_1T_2T_3=
     \begin{bmatrix} C_1&-S_1&S_1&0\\S_1&C_1&-C_1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
     \begin{bmatrix}
     C_2&-S_2&0&a_2C_2\\S_2&C_2&0&a_2S_2\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
     \begin{bmatrix}  C_3&-S_3&0&a_3C_3\\S_3&C_3&0&a_3S_3\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
     \]

\end{solution}

\question this is the question

\begin{solution}
The DH parameters:
\nopagebreak

 \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
 Link& $b_i$& $\theta_i$& $a_i$ & $\alpha_i$\\
  \hline
 1 & $b_1$ & $\theta_1$ & $a_1$& 0\\
  \hline
 2 & $b_2$ & $\theta_2$ & $a_2$& 0\\
  \hline
 3 & $b_3$ &0 & 0& 0\\
  \hline
 4& $b_4$ & $\theta_4$ & 0& 0\\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}

 \[T=T_1T_2T_3=
   \begin{bmatrix} C_1&-S_1&S_1&0\\S_1&C_1&-C_1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \begin{bmatrix}
   C_2&-S_2&0&a_2C_2\\S_2&C_2&0&a_2S_2\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \begin{bmatrix}  C_3&-S_3&0&a_3C_3\\S_3&C_3&0&a_3S_3\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
   \]

   \[T=T_1T_2T_3=
     \begin{bmatrix} C_1&-S_1&S_1&0\\S_1&C_1&-C_1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
     \begin{bmatrix}
     C_2&-S_2&0&a_2C_2\\S_2&C_2&0&a_2S_2\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
     \begin{bmatrix}  C_3&-S_3&0&a_3C_3\\S_3&C_3&0&a_3S_3\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \quad
     \]

\end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add the `[b]` option to the table solved the issue, I believe the true solution is the `solution` environment should take care of this issue. About the equation empty line, I just copy and paste the equations to make a minimal sample code, I do use multiply line equations in my original code.

Comment: I noticed that not only the tabular, but also the equation could touch the border of the solution's frame when the solution is crossing the pages. So, I have turn the border off by using the command `\unframedsolutions`. By reading the document of the `exam` class, I see it use the `\fbox` as the solution's frame box.